# How many different classifications of people are there in The Handmaid’s Tale?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

In the TV series *The Handmaid's Tale* we see a dystopian future where people live in classes.

I have heard of:

- Ant - A worker
- Eye - Spy/Secret Police
- Aunt - Keeper of the Handmaidens
- Commander - Boss of some kind (I don't know if it is political or military)
- Martha - housekeeper
- Handmaid - Walking baby machines

Are there any other classifications and what do they mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are all the classes from the book by Margaret Atwood, which the TV show is based on. Presumably they all exist in the show as well, but we haven't seen all of them yet. [You can also see a list on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handmaid%27s_Tale#Gender_and_occupation)

#### Women

- Legitimate women

  - Wife – Married to a man of the ruling class (wears blue, or black if she's a widow)
  - Daughter – Natural or adopted female child of the ruling class (wears white until marriage)
  - Handmaid – Fertile women of a lower class (who have broken gender/social laws) who bear children for infertile wives (wears red)
  - Aunt – Keeper of the Handmaids, as you say; often older, infertile or unmarried women (wears brown)
  - Martha – Housekeeper; older infertile women (wears green)
  - Econowife – Married to a man of a lower class; are not assigned Marthas or Handmaids (and wears a multicolored red, blue and green dress because they fill all these functions). As far as I remember, this hasn't been seen in the show yet, but I don't think it's much of a spoiler to mention it.
- Illegitimate women

  - Unwoman – Can't be integrated into society, who are exiled to the Colonies
  - > Jezebel – Prostitutes and entertainers of the higher class

#### Men

- Legitimate men

  - Commander – The ruling class, often with a high political status as you say (think "members of the Party" in the USSR)
  - Men – "regular" men of lower classes; can marry Econowives and hold regular jobs
  - Eye – Secret police
  - Angel – Soldiers
  - Guardian – Police/security force and other menial functions
- Illegitimate men

  - Gender Traitors – homosexuals and similar, who are either executed outright or sent to the colonies

I can't recall "Ants" having been mentioned. Are you sure you didn't mishear "Aunts"?

Comment: episode 5 the commander mentioned an ant running across the border to Canada. He was sitting at a table speaking to his wife about it. I think it was "Ant" i heard.

Comment: @Cherubel Pretty sure that was an Aunt. Turn on closed captions to verify (or I can do it later today).

Comment: Why the one spoiler?

Comment: @SQB The existence of that particular class of women was a fairly major unveiling. I see that it's been spoiled in a comment to the question already, though, so I guess it's not really that important.

Comment: @SQB Answering in a comment is not necessarily a reason to flag it. If it's made obsolete by an actual answer (as in this case) then it's obsolete, but if not then it should be left so that someone can use it to write up an answer.

Comment: @tobiasvl what about the men doing all the menial labor? in the show we see a few men digging, handling dead bodies etc... i dont suppose that the other classes of men would do this job as they have to stand there with their guns looking menacing and listening to some idiot on the radio the entire time!

Comment: @Cherubel You're quite right – "regular" men were missing from the list since they're the "default" class. I assume many of the men we see who are doing menial labour are Guardians, men who are older, disabled, stupid, young or otherwise unsuitable for regular jobs. Other lower-class men (who are fit to marry Econowives) make up the bulk of the male population. _Perhaps_ they're called "Ants" in the show, although that phrase doesn't appear in the novel? Do you recall the timestamp in episode 5 when you heard it?

Comment: I seem to recall from the book that there was an additional category of male religious heretics or cultists - one of them was labeled with the initial "J" and it was speculated (but never determined) whether the "J" meant "Jew" or "Jehovah's Witness", two religious which apparently were both banned in the universe.